# Laravel DatabaseMigrations produces error: Call to a member function call() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to run DatabaseMigrations on my unit tests, but I get the following error:

```
1) VisitStaffPagesTest::testLogBills
Error: Call to a member function call() on null

/Users/x/Documents/office/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/ApplicationTrait.php:312
/Users/x/Documents/office/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/DatabaseMigrations.php:12
```

From DatabaseMigrations:

```
public function runDatabaseMigrations()
{
    $this->artisan('migrate'); // This is line 12

    $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () {
        $this->artisan('migrate:rollback');
    });
}
```

From ApplicationTrait:

```
public function artisan($command, $parameters = [])
{
    return $this->code = $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel']->call($command, $parameters);
}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Show code of your `VisitStaffPagesTest` class

Comment: Here it is: http://kopy.io/TZn9o

Comment: Where do you have defined `createApplication` method ?

Comment: That's in TestCase: http://kopy.io/MfiqP

Comment: New detail here: this only happens on on my Mac, not on my live server (CentOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this using this code in my TestCase.php file:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    $this->code = $app['Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel']->call('migrate');
    $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () use ($app) {
        $app['Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel']->call('migrate:rollback');
    });

    return $app;
}
```

Essentially I'm just calling the migration and rollbacks manually. Not sure why it works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify `createApplication` method in your `TestCase` from

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    return $app;
}
```

to:

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    $this->app = $app;  // line added

    return $app;
}
```

Comment: I edited it, but I have the same error: 'Error: Call to a member function call() on null'